# Need assistance in making a simple kiosk app

Tags: google-chrome, webview, kiosk, google-chrome-os

I'm looking for some help in creating an application that will accept user input for a URL and then present Chrome in kiosk mode. Ideally, the URL would remain persistent and no additional dialog would interfere with the application unless the device is powerwashed. Upon reboot, no URL entry would be requested and the previous entered URL would simply load.

I have followed the sample code to create a persistent kiosk application with a hard-coded URL, but would greatly appreciate some help in making this more dynamic. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here are my files:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <title>Chrome Kiosk</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
   <webview id="map" src="http://www.google.com" style="width:1920px; 
   height:1080px" partition="persist:vfcache"></webview>
</body>

</html>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
  "name": "Chrome Kiosk",
  "version": "0.9",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png",
    "16": "icon_16.png"
  },

  "app": {
    "background": {
       "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
      "persistent": false
    }
  },

  "permissions": [
    "power",
    "storage",
    "webview"
  ],

  "kiosk_enabled": true

}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {

  chrome.power.requestKeepAwake('display');

  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    'outerBounds': {
    'width': 1920,
    'height': 1080  
    }
  });

});
```